# Date time : ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, series, valueerror

I am looking to compare two *dataframe* `end1` and `tt1`, what I want to do is to see when if an event in `tt1` influences an event in `end1` at roughly the same time

When I am trying to create a simple *loop* to look for events at roughly the same time , I get the error message :

`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

```
end1['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(end1['end_date'], format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
tt1['Minstart'] = pd.to_datetime(tt1['Minstart'], format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
tt1['Maxstart'] = pd.to_datetime(tt1['Maxstart'], format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')

for index, row in end1.iterrows():
    if  end1['end_date'] > tt1['Minstart']:
        if  end1['end_date'] < tt1['Maxstart']:
            d = end1.count(end1.end_date)
            print(d)
```

both are :
     `pandas.core.series.Series`

Thank you

Comment: what pd.to_datetime function do?

Comment: I used it to make sure all the dates had the same format

Comment: can you print the format and type of  end1['end_date']?

Comment: the type is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: the format is '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'

Comment: looks like this : 2016-10-07 09:19:00

Comment: Your format doesn't match your sample text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems the `int_overlaps` function from the `lubridate` package, makes it possible to know if two dates overlaps, and then I am able to choose the events where the `int_overlaps` is 'TRUE'

However not all overlaps appear as `TRUE` , I don't understand the reason why